# написать функцию роутер php

Tags: php

на процедурке без ООП и классов можно сделать роутер?

Например так

```
routes('/' => 'index.php',    
'authorize' => 'author8ze.php'    
);
```

Если пройдите по ссылке site.ru/authorize открывается authorize.php

помогите)) у меня не получается..

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

index.php

```
<?php

function router($routes = [])
{
    $request_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $request_path = rtrim($request_path, '/');
    $request_path = empty($request_path) ? '/' : $request_path;

    foreach ($routes as $path => $file) {

        if ($request_path === $path) {
            require $file;
            return;
        }

    }

    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}


router([
    '/' => '1.php',
    '/test' => '2.php'
]);
```

Comment: спасибо)) а можно так? route('/log' , '1.php') { функция log(); } route('/reg' , '1.php') { reg(); } знаю тут не фриланс сайт) просто интересно

Comment: Ну, вот так нечто похожее
    foreach ($routes as $path => $function) {
        if ($request_path === $path) {
            return call_user_func($function);
        }
    }



router([
    '/' => function () {
        var_dump(1);
    },
    '/test' => function() {
        var_dump(2);
    }
]);